# Android React-Native - Shadows using elevation stopped working

Tags: android, react-native, shadow, elevation

Edit - found the problem: I figured out I was using hardwareAccelerated="false" but that's actually needed for elevation

I recently made some updates to my app and all of the elevation shadows that were previously working on Android no longer work. My iOS shadows using the shadow properties are still there though.

An example of the styles I set for one of my components is:

```
{
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  borderRadius: borderRadius,
  elevation: 2,
}
```

All of my elevation properties are accompanied with a backgroundColor applied and they were working previously so I don't believe there's anything wrong with the styling implementation.

Comment: What kind of style did you use to show the shadow?

Comment: @hongdeveloper I'm using the 'elevation' property. I edited my post with a code sample showing how I used it.

Comment: So I figured out my issue - I was using hardwareAccelerated="false" and you need hardware acceleration in order to have elevation